# binding htmlagility data between c# and xaml (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, html-agility-pack, uwp

How to bind data which

i just grabbed with HTMLagility in background

(C#)with XAML???

and make it shown in my app(i meant UWP isnt like Winform App which can use console.writeline to give the output and i dont know hot to bind htmlagility Data with Xaml)

just at those blank position

[Picture s here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/868072)

and here's part of my code

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Net.Http.HttpClient
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        
        var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;

        string header = "ie";
        if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
        }

        header = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
        if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
        }

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

       
        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

                    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(" http://www.google.de");
         
        if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
        {
            

        }
        else
        {

            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

                if (bodyNode != null)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's few options:

First option is to check the MSDN blog ["Displaying HTML Content in a RichTextBlock"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2013/05/13/displaying-html-content-in-a-richtextblock/). That shows the code you need to convert your HTML to RichTextBlock. Not the easiest solution but it works.

Second option is to use one of the available converters. For example [Html2Xaml](http://winrthtml2xaml.codeplex.com/) could work.

Third option is to use WebView to display your HTML. This could be the easiest way to get going. After you have the HTML body as a string, you can display it using [WebView.NavigateToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,if i wanna parse a table from Web then can i still use first two options?